How to Define an Array of Generic Interface Types with Varying Type Parameters in TypeScript?
I'm working with TypeScript interfaces and need some help with passing generics. Here’s a simplified version of my issue.
I have an IGetInquiryProps interface that contains a tableArray property, which is an array of IAntDataGridConvertedProps elements. The IAntDataGridConvertedProps interface requires three generic types (T, K, G) to be specified, but the elements in the tableArray array are not fixed.
export interface baseLazyParam {
  first?: number;
  rows: number;
  page: number;
  sortOrder?: number;
  sortField?: string;
}

export type extraPrams<InputQuery> = Omit<
  InputQuery,
  | 'sortingParams'
  | 'filterParam'
  | 'groupingColumns'
  | 'pageNumber'
  | 'pageSize'
>;

// Create a mapped type where keys are the same as BaseProperties
export type IFilter<T> = Record<keyof T, IFilterProperty>;

export type ILazyParam<InputQuery, selectedFilters> = baseLazyParam &
  extraPrams<InputQuery> & { filters: IFilter<selectedFilters> };

export interface IFilterProperty {
  operator: string;
  constraints: any[];
}

export interface IGetInquiryProps <?,?,?>{
  headerCardGroupProps: any;
  footerCardGroupProps: any;
  tableArray: IAntDataGridConvertedProps<?,?,?>[];
  footerButtonsModalProps: any;
}

export interface IAntDataGridConvertedProps<T, K, G> {
  path?: string;
  ApiObj?: any;
  Columns?: any[];
  tbData?: G[];
  lazyParam?: ILazyParam<T, K>;
  recallApi?: boolean;
  // Other properties...
}


//How I used your suggestion
const GetInquiryIndividualSamaCheque = forwardRef((props: IProps, ref) => {
  const { recordData, requestData, samaChequeSourceDetailId, showFooter } =
    props;
  const { getInquiryProps } = useLogicGetInquiryIndividualSamaCheque({
    ref,
    recordData,
    requestData,
    showFooter,
    samaChequeSourceDetailId,
  });

  return (
    <GetInquiry<
      [
        GetAllSamaChequeDetailControlsQuery,
        GetAllSamaChequeDetailControlsQuery,
      ],
      [
        selectedFiltersGetInquirySamaCheque,
        selectedFiltersGetInquirySamaCheque,
      ],
      [SamaChequeDetailControlViewModel, SamaChequeDetailControlViewModel]
    >
      {...getInquiryProps}
    />
  );
});


function GetInquiry<T, K, G>(props: IGetInquiryProps<T, K, G>) {
  const {
    headerCardGroupProps,
    footerCardGroupProps,
    tableArray,
    footerButtonsModalProps,
  } = props;

  return (
    <>
      {headerCardGroupProps && (
        <DataDisplayCardGroup {...headerCardGroupProps} />
      )}
      {tableArray?.map((tbData, index) => {
        return <AntDataGridConvert {...tbData} key={index} />;
      })}
      {footerCardGroupProps && (
        <DataDisplayCardGroup {...footerCardGroupProps} />
      )}
      {footerButtonsModalProps && (
        <FooterButtonsModal {...footerButtonsModalProps} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}



#Simple example and solution
import ChildComponent from '@pages/example/ChildComponent.tsx';

export interface A1 {
  a1: number;
}

export interface A2 {
  a2: number;
}

export interface B1 {
  b1: number;
}

export interface B2 {
  b2: number;
}

export interface C1 {
  data: {
    id: number;
    header: string;
    flag: boolean;
    title: string;
  }[];
}

export interface C2 {
  data: {
    id: number;
    header: string;
    flag: boolean;
    title: string;
  }[];
}

function ParentComponent() {
  const apiA1 = { a1: 1 };
  const paramsB1 = { b1: 1 };
  const tbDataC1 = {
    data: [
      {
        id: 101,
        header: 'some thing 1',
        flag: true,
        title: 'table title 1',
      },
    ],
  };
  const apiA2 = { a2: 1 };
  const paramsB2 = { b2: 1 };
  const tbDataC2 = {
    data: [
      {
        id: 103,
        header: 'some thing 3',
        flag: false,
        title: 'table title 3',
      },
    ],
  };
  return (
    <ChildComponent<[A1, A2], [B1, B2], [C1, C2]>
      tableArray={[
        { api: apiA1, params: paramsB1, tbData: tbDataC1 },
        {
          api: apiA2,
          params: paramsB2,
          tbData: tbDataC2,
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
}

export default ParentComponent;

import AntDataGridConvert from '@/component/AntDataGrid/AntDataGridConvert.tsx';
import { IAntDataGridConvertedProps } from '@/component/AntDataGrid/types.ts';

export interface ITable<T, K, G> {
  api: T;
  params: K;
  tbData: G;
}

export interface IChildComponent<
  T extends any[],
  K extends Record<keyof T, any>,
  G extends Record<keyof T, any>,
> {
  tableArray: { [I in keyof T]: ITable<T[I], K[I], G[I]> };
}

function ChildComponent<
  T extends any[],
  K extends Record<keyof T, any>,
  G extends Record<keyof T, any>,
>({ tableArray }: IChildComponent<T, K, G>) {
  return (
    <div>
      {(
        tableArray as {
          [I in keyof T]: IAntDataGridConvertedProps<T[I], K[I], G[I]>;
        }
      )?.map((props, index) => {
        return <AntDataGridConvert {...props} key={index} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChildComponent;



If IGetInquiryProps is not generic, then you should specify the concrete types as type arguments when defining tableArray.

• Please [edit] to provide a [mre] where you either declare your custom types (like IColumnsProps etc) or you replace them with built-in stuff so that we don't see errors you're not asking about when we look in our IDEs. • You can use mapped array types as shown in this playground link but without a [mre] showing how you intend to use it, it's hard to be sure. Is that what you're looking for? If so I could write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

I have replaced any for not defined types to make it simpler and remove errors. I have checked the link you provided but I do not get it. Could you please explain more?

Now my link looks like this version. You see how the three type parameters become tuples? So you pass in three tuples T, K, and G, and then the tableArray property looks like [IProps<T[0],K[0],G[0]>, IProps<T[1],K[1],G[1]> ...]. I'm not sure what to do if you still don't "get it". Maybe you could [edit] more with code that uses your types and I can show you how to apply it?

Thank you, I think I got it. but I have a problem. T1, T2, K1, ..G3 are all generics. How should I pass them in the middle component? Now I am getting error. I have added how I used what you suggested in the problem definition above.

What's forwardRef? What's IProps? What's ref? etc etc etc. I need a [mre] or I can't see what your issue is through all the other issues my IDE complains about. I do hope that this problem is directly relevant to your current question as asked, and is not just the next problem you ran into after solving your current one.  That is, the goal is to answer your original question, not to guide you through and then past it into other stuff. If you can [edit] to show a [mre] (and minimal is important) where IGetInquiryProps is being used, maybe I can help. Otherwise ‍♂️

ForwardRef is a feature in react to pass ref in components. I don't know whether you know React but I've just copied some parts of my code to show you how I pass the types through components. You will get errros. My question is I am getting errors in GetInquiry component that T is not any[] or Property 'map' does not exist on type '{ [I in keyof T]: IAntDataGridConvertedProps<T[I], K[I], G[I]>; }'. I think those errors are coming back to the way I passed on generic types in GetInquiry component. I don't know what could be the correct way?

It needs to be a [mre] or I can't say much. A [mre] is not just copying some parts of your code; it's a... you should just click on the link and read about it if you haven't already. At this point I'm just repeating myself.

Thank you. I have solved the problem and add the solution in problem description.

If you have solved the problem then please post it as an answer below, not as an edit to the question.

Do you mean something like this:
export interface IAntDataGridConvertedProps<T, K, G> {
  path?: string;
  ApiObj?: any;
  Columns?: IColumnsProps<G>[];
  tbData?: G[];
  lazyParam?: ILazyParam<T, K>;
  recallApi?: boolean;
  [key: string]: any;
}

